# Why aiohttp deprecated the loop parameter in ClientSession?

Tags: python, aiohttp

In the aiohttp's [doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#client-session) reads:

> - loop –
>     event loop used for processing HTTP requests.
>     If loop is None the constructor borrows it from connector if specified.
>     asyncio.get_event_loop() is used for getting default event loop otherwise.
>
> Deprecated since version 2.0.

I googled but didn't get any description about why the `loop` parameter is deprecated.

I often create `ClientSession` object like this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)
```

Now the `loop` parameter is depracted, but just call `aiohttp.ClientSession()` without the loop will get a warning:

> Creating a client session outside of coroutine

So why the parameter is deprecated and how to use the session correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is addressed [in this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3331) which is advising that the client session object be created within a coroutine to avoid errors that are difficult to debug. The preferred usage is [demonstrated here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html); for reference:

```
async def fetch(client):
    async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue link is very helpful.

Comment: aoihttp also advises to use a single session for your entire application to improve connection pooling. I don't see how you can do this in a reasonable way with this use pattern